# Reading a ditamap in ant xslt task

Tags: ant, xslt-2.0, saxon, dita

I'm trying to read ditamap file from my XSLT stylesheet processing using fn:doc() function. But ant fails because DTD public identifier cannot be resolved even if there is catalog file specified.

[ditamap: mKeyDefUi.ditamap]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map>
   <keydef keys="UI_Action">
      <topicmeta>
         <keywords>
            <keyword>処理</keyword>
         </keywords>
      </topicmeta>
   </keydef>
   <keydef keys="UI_ActionAfterPrinting">
      <topicmeta>
         <keywords>
            <keyword>印刷終了時の設定</keyword>
         </keywords>
      </topicmeta>
   </keydef>
   ...
</map>
```

[ant buld.xml main part]

```
<property name="key.map.url" value="file:/D:/SVN/acme-dev/VisualWorks/ja-JP/keydef-map/mKeyDefUi.ditamap"/>
<property name="dita.catalog.file" value="/D:/DITA-OT/dita-ot-2.5.2/catalog-dita.xml"/>
...
<!-- Main target -->
<target name="uicontrol.conv">
    <echo message="topic.file.prop=${topic.file.prop}"/>
    <antcall target="uicontrol.conv.impl">
        <param name="prmTopicFileProp" value="${topic.file.prop}"/>
        <param name="prmOutputDirUrl" value="${output.dir.url}"/>
        <param name="prmKeyMapUrl" value="${key.map.url}"/>
        <param name="prmLogFileUrl" value="${log.file.url}"/>
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="uicontrol.conv.impl">
    <property name="dummy.input" value="${basedir}/dummy-in.xml"/>
    <property name="dummy.output" value="${basedir}/dummy-out.xml"/>
    <property name="xsl.file" value="${basedir}/xsl/convUicontrol.xsl"/>
    <xslt processor="trax" in="${dummy.input}" out="${dummy.output}" style="${xsl.file}" force="true">
        <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
        <param name="PRM_TOPIC_FILE_PROP" expression="${prmTopicFileProp}"/>
        <param name="PRM_OUTPUT_DIR_URL" expression="${prmOutputDirUrl}"/>
        <param name="PRM_KEY_MAP_URL" expression="${prmKeyMapUrl}"/>
        <param name="PRM_LOG_FILE_URL" expression="${prmLogFileUrl}"/>
        <xmlcatalog>
            <catalogpath>
                <pathelement location="${dita.catalog.file}"/>
            </catalogpath>
        </xmlcatalog>
    </xslt>
</target>
```

[The ant log]

```
Executing:
"c:\program files\oxygen xml editor 19\jre/bin/java" -Xmx256m -classpath "C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 19\tools\ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar" "-Dant.home=C:\Program Files\Oxygen XML Editor 19\tools\ant" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -lib "D:\My_Documents\Java\SaxonPE9-8-0-3J\saxon9pe.jar" -lib "D:\My_Documents\Java\xml-commons-resolver-1.2\resolver.jar" -lib "D:\My_Documents\Java\xml-commons-external-1.4.01\xml-apis.jar" -lib "D:\My_Documents\Java\xml-commons-external-1.4.01\xml-apis-ext.jar" -f "build.xml" "-Dwebhelp.trial.license=no" -v -d

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.8 compiled on December 25 2016
Buildfile: D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\build.xml
Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
Detected Java version: 1.8 in: c:\program files\oxygen xml editor 19\jre
Detected OS: Windows 8.1
...

uicontrol.conv.impl:
Setting project property: dummy.input -> D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv/dummy-in.xml
Setting project property: dummy.output -> D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv/dummy-out.xml
Setting project property: xsl.file -> D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv/xsl/convUicontrol.xsl
     [xslt] Using class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison
     [xslt] In file D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\dummy-in.xml time: 1504138459522
     [xslt] Out file D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\dummy-out.xml time: 0
     [xslt] Style file D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv/xsl/convUicontrol.xsl time: 1504138455268
     [xslt] Processing D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\dummy-in.xml to D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\dummy-out.xml
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\xsl\convUicontrol.xsl
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: _isNotSecureProcessing
resolve: 'util_string.xsl' with base: 'file:/D:/SVN/acme/key/uicontrol-conv/xsl/convUicontrol.xsl'
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.resolver.ApacheCatalogResolver loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Apache resolver library found, xml-commons resolver will be used
Using catalogpath 'D:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.5.2\catalog-dita.xml'
Parsing D:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.5.2\catalog-dita.xml
resolve: 'file:/D:/SVN/acme-dev/VisualWorks/ja-JP/keydef-map/mKeyDefUi.ditamap' with base: 'file:/D:/SVN/acme/key/uicontrol-conv/xsl/convUicontrol.xsl'
resolveEntity: '-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN': 'file:/D:/SVN/acme-dev/VisualWorks/ja-JP/keydef-map/map.dtd'
No matching catalog entry found, parser will use: 'file:/D:/SVN/acme-dev/VisualWorks/ja-JP/keydef-map/map.dtd'
     [xslt] D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\xsl\convUicontrol.xsl:17:4: Fatal Error! I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/D:/SVN/acme-dev/VisualWorks/ja-JP/keydef-map/mKeyDefUi.ditamap: D:\SVN\acme-dev\VisualWorks\ja-JP\keydef-map\map.dtd (Specified file does not found.) Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\SVN\acme-dev\VisualWorks\ja-JP\keydef-map\map.dtd (Specified file does not found.)
     [xslt] Failed to process D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\dummy-in.xml
  [antcall] Exiting D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\build.xml.

BUILD FAILED
D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\build.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\build.xml:32: Fatal error during transformation using D:\SVN\acme\key\uicontrol-conv\xsl\convUicontrol.xsl: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/D:/SVN/acme-dev/VisualWorks/ja-JP/keydef-map/mKeyDefUi.ditamap: D:\SVN\acme-dev\VisualWorks\ja-JP\keydef-map\map.dtd (Specified file does not found.); SystemID: file:/D:/SVN/acme/key/uicontrol-conv/xsl/convUicontrol.xsl; Line#: 17; Column#: 4
```

The xslt task loaded the newest DITA-OT catalog file. But public identifier '-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN' was not resolved.
What is wrong with my build.xml?

Comment: It looks to me as if the public identifier WAS resolved, but it was resolved to the wrong thing. Beyond that, I'm afraid I'm no expert on catalogs and my start point for debugging would be the same as yours, but with less information about the contents of your filestore.

Comment: The relevant ant source code: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28924649/

Comment: See if you can take Ant out of the equation and get it to run using Saxon from the command line with the -catalog option. Whether it works or not, you'll learn something from the exercise. If you set the Saxon -t option then the resolver's logging should be enabled.

Comment: @MicaelKay I’ve tested Saxon command-line specifying –catalog parameter. The result messages ware bit different but anyway the transformation has been failed with missing DTD message. I think that there are two problems. One is ant problem because ant surely displays error message in their module. The other is Saxon specific because command-line also fails. I will submit a question using simpler test case in Saxon help mailing-list.

Comment: Actually if we've eliminated Ant then the next thing to eliminate is Saxon. Saxon does very little with the catalog request other than passing it on to the next layer down...

Answer (score 0):

You should also try to add a classpath reference to the Xerces library "xercesImpl.jar".
Also this error line in your console output:

```
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: _isNotSecureProcessing
```

would seem to indicate that there is an attempt to use the Xalan TransformerFactoryImpl.

Comment: When adding xercesImpl.jar, ant uses it instead of com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal. But the result was not changed. Also the stylesheet uses XSLT 3.0 capabilities. Removing document type declaration from ditamap produces the expected result. This means that SaxonPE9-8-0-3J works fine in this build.xml.

Comment: Then you should try Michael Kay's suggestion of trying to build a command line and get Ant out of the equation...